# AFNetworking (v 2) crashing on self.HTTPError

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Xcode crash logs retrieved from iTunesConnect shows the crash on that first line

```
    if (self.HTTPError) {
        return self.HTTPError;
    } else {
        return [super error];
    }
}
```

next line down in the stacktrace is

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-retain-cycles"
    self.completionBlock = ^ {
        dispatch_async(image_request_operation_processing_queue(), ^(void) {
            if (self.error) {
```

on the last line is where the error indicator shows.

Does this mean `self` was nil?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the symbolicated crash log and the actual error message as well.

Comment: That's all Xcode gives me unfortunately